# Extract tables from a pdf with blurred images

Tags: python, ocr

Im trying to use Python to extract tables from pages in a pdf that has blurred images in it. It only has images on each page and there is no text in it.

For example this is a table on the second page:
[image]

I tried the following code to convert each page into a png img but it converts each page into 19 smaller images and this cuts off the table :

```
import fitz
import os

# Open the PDF file
# get_image_bce
pdf_file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '1990-01-01 Oil Market Report (IEA).pdf')
pdf_file = fitz.open(pdf_file_path)

# Select a page to extract the image from
page = pdf_file[1]


img_list = page.get_images()


# image_list = page.getImageList()
for i in range(len(img_list)):

    if img_list:
        # Extract the image data
        xref = img_list[i][0]
        pix = fitz.Pixmap(pdf_file, xref)
        if pix.n > 4:
            print("n > 4")
            pix = fitz.Pixmap(fitz.csRGB, pix)
        pix.save(f"ocr-images{i}.png")
```

This is one of the images that it produces :

[image]

I'm wondering that is there an easier way to save these tables as csvs.

I've also tried tabula, but it created an empty csv file :

```
tabula.convert_into(path, "output.csv", output_format="csv", stream=True, pages='all')
```

This is the link to one of the pdf files :

**https://drive.google.com/file/d/19qVO0DFVE4TdamYa44MEIZrQ7Dkb9JUC/view?usp=sharing**