# Extract tables from Images as csvs

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have a few pdf where each page is a blurred image, I wanted to extract tables from its pages and save each table as a separate csv, hence I asked this question:

[Extract tables from a pdf with blurred images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75572366/extract-tables-from-a-pdf-with-blurred-images)

Afterwards, I was able to convert each page of the pdf into a .jpeg image and used TesseractOCR to extract info from the image, it was able to pick the info but it seems to be skipping some fields and not keeping the format as in the images :

This is the image of the table:
[image]

and this is the generated csv from this :
[image]

As you can see that motor gasoline has two subheadings under it, but % change is skipped.

And if there was a way to keep the same formatting as motor gasoline was supposed to be the heading for 2 columns not just first column (can fix this manually via loops if needed).

This is my code so far (apart from code that converts pdf pages to images) :

```
def extract_data_from_table_ocr():
    from img2table.ocr import TesseractOCR
    from img2table.document import Image

    # Instantiation of OCR
    ocr = TesseractOCR(n_threads=1, lang="eng")

    # Instantiation of document, either an image or a PDF
    doc = Image('out3.jpg', dpi=200)

    # Table extraction
    extracted_tables_all = doc.extract_tables(ocr=ocr,
                                        implicit_rows=True,
                                        borderless_tables=True,
                                        min_confidence=50)
    print("length : " , len(extracted_tables_all))
    extracted_tables = extracted_tables_all[0]
    frames = []
    for table in extracted_tables_all:
        try:
            frames.append(table.df)
        except:
            frames.append(table)

        
  
    result = pd.concat(frames)
    
    result.to_csv('tableConverted2.csv', index=False, header = False)
```

Comment: the documents are pretty old and only available in pdf format

Comment: This link is the free dataset, the pdfs that I've gotten are paid and only kept for specific time periods.